# Regex: Get all words until a number of a special character is found

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract movie names from a list that looks like this:

> The Maze Runner 2014 DVDRip XviD MP3-RARBG
>
> Fury 2014 DVDSCR x264 AC3-Blackjesus
>
> Dracula's Untold Story (WebRip / 2014)

I need to extract the words up to the year or a special character like `(` or `[`  but not `'`

> The Maze Runner 2014 DVDRip XviD MP3-RARBG  ==> The Maze Runner
>
> Fury 2014 DVDSCR x264 AC3-Blackjesus ==> Fury
>
> Dracula's Untold Story (WebRip / 2014) == Dracula's Untold Story
>
> Dracula's Untold Story [WebRip / 2014] == Dracula's Untold Story

I have no idea how to go on about writing a complex regex like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Practically,it's not possible to parse each of the movie any of the possible way! The idea seems vague! You need to lay more emphasis for a stricter regex.

Comment: Or `Death Race 2000 1975 DVDRip XviD MP3-RARBG`

Comment: @anubhava- ANd this too `MP3 2013 XviD MP3`...

Comment: @anubhava The list is of movies, they will only have 1 year part

Comment: Right I understand but `2012` and `Death Race 2000` are just the **names of the movies**.

Comment: If the year of the movie is always present and if the formats are limited, it is possible because the backtracking will do the job. Otherwise, it is not possible without an human eye or a database.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: What if movie name itself contains 4 digits like `Death Race 2000`

Comment: @anubhava: it's not a problem if the year of the movie is present later in the string.

Comment: @anubhava thats a good point. The list is basically is 99% of movies from the last few months. so I guess the number part of the regex should match 2014/2015 only. that will make it a little more better

Comment: Free form parsing "up to" `like ( or [ but not '` will be the death nail. No matter what you do, it won't be good enough. Have to define hard delimiters.

Comment: Hard delimiters can be an abstract concept, not restricted by usual anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\ '-]+(?=\b\d{4}\b|\()
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/4

Comment: This is pretty good. Any idea why it wouldn't watch The hunger games? http://regex101.com/r/lQ6oS4/1

Comment: Now its great. it even matches title that have a year in their name like space odyssey 2001 1968. awesome

Comment: Hi. can you figure out why it is matching wrongly on the last three titles http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/2

Answer (score 2):

The below code snippet can be helpful to meet your requirements

```
public static String extractMovieName(String movieNameString){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w' ]+)([\\[]|[\\(]|[\\d]{4})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(movieNameString);
        String extractedName = "";
        if(matcher.find()){
            extractedName =  matcher.group(1);
        }
        return extractedName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

**Example:**

```
System.out.println("Fury 2014 DVDSCR x264 AC3-Blackjesus".replaceAll("\\s(\\d|\\(|\\[).*", ""));
```